# Datatables 1.10.3 Ajax Load Columns Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

i have the following problem:

In my mvc-application, i have to load the data with an ajaxload. This works very fine. But in the datatable the blabla has a shorter lenghts like the column in the ajax call { "data": "blablablablabla" }. So in the table it is shown like:
blabla (header)
blabl-
ablab-
labla-
...

So i want to set the column width longer as the !!!

Here my code snippets:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="table3">
            <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
                <table id="Artikelstamm" class="table dt-index" cellspacing="0" style="width: 150%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>ArtID</th>
                            <th>MarkennameRad</th>
                            <th>MarkennameMotor</th>
                            <th>MarkennameZusatz</th>
                            <th>TypSchlüssel</th>
......
......
```

And the ajax call:

```
$('#Artikelstamm').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "lengthMenu": [[100, 125, 150], [100, 125, 150]],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("List1", "DFS_Akustik")",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ID" },
                { "data": "ArtID" },
                { "data": "MarkennameRad" },
                { "data": "MarkennameMotor" },
                { "data": "MarkennameZusatz" },
                { "data": "TypSchluessel" },
```

Sorry i can't set an image here...

I want that it is: ZN050-SDL.4F.V7P7
and not:
ZN050-
SDL.4F.V7P7

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Greetz
Vegeta_77

Comment: So the solution is: th, td { white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; };

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept it. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.